# typedef enum is not working C++

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-errors

I have a very basic question.

.h

```
private:
list <int> Stack;

typedef enum
{
    Push,
    Pop,
    Min,
    Display
}Operation;

Operation map(string s);
```

.Cpp:

```
Operation min_Stack::map(string s)
{
```

The compiler is not complaining for .h file but for .cpp its giving error : "identifier operation is unidentified".

I am unable to find what I did wrong here.

Comment: The problem is unrelated to the `typedef`. The `enum` is declared in the scope of `min_stack`.

Comment: Don't do `typedef enum ` (or `struct`, or `class`) `{} X;`, it's a Cism. Just write `enum X {};`.

Comment: In C++, the `typedef` is not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
Operation min_Stack::map(string s)
```

write

```
min_Stack::Operation min_Stack::map(string s)
```

The compiler searches the return type in the namespace scope and it did not find the name because the name is defined inside class min_Stack.

Comment: wow.. how silly of me.. will accept this answer as soon as the site allows me :)